# Switching between virtual desktops with and without VPN: Do I need a VM for this?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vpn

On a windows 10 machine I would like to use my university's VPN for browsing academic stuff, and at the same time use the internet connection without VPN for unrelated pages (i.e., when connected to a VPN-LAN, which kicks me out when I switch to another VPN due to security). One useful feature I would find using is Windows Virtual Desktops, which allow for seamless switching between the workspaces. However, enabling the VPN in one virtual desktop, naturally, works for the other ones. I would like to somehow separate those two workspaces, but with the ability of an easy switch between them.

**My Idea as a workaround** would be running a VM on another Virtual Desktop in full screen, where inside the VM I would connect to the VPN. If I imagine it correctly, it shouldn't get passed over to the host machine.

**My question: Is such approach legit, or are there better approaches (with, I hope less overhead) for such setup?**

Comment: Can you do a VPN split?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen I do not know. I will look into it, thanks. Would it help splitting the traffic at a FQDN level, or at a web-browser level (like, i.e., would running browsers traffic through a HTTP proxy)?

Comment: While the desktops might provide virtual separation, your devices are not separate, Windows does not provide the feature required to do what you describe.  While connected to the VPN, the VPN would be applicable, to all virtual desktops.  In the case, you describe all internet traffic will go through the VPN, unless an application is configured to use a different adapter.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, yeah, I had such suspicion. Would switching users (without logging-off) change the network device used? Although, I'm not sure it would be as seamless as a separate VM.